# Why is ActualWidth/ActualHeight don't changed after performing RenderTransform?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, scale, rendertransform, actualwidth

I have the following code to resize an image control

```
    private void ApplyScale()
    {
        ((CompositeTransform)img.RenderTransform).ScaleX = TotalImageScale;
        ((CompositeTransform)img.RenderTransform).ScaleY = TotalImageScale;
        Debug.WriteLine("img.Width: " + img.Width.ToString() + " - img.ActualWidth: " + img.ActualWidth.ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine("img.Height: " + img.Height.ToString() + " - img.ActualHeight: " + img.ActualHeight.ToString()); 

    }
```

While the code works properly, I am trying to understand why the image `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` do not change after the scaling. They are always the same as the `Width` and `Height` values.

How do I get the new image control size? Do I have to calculate it manually via the scale change ratio?

Answer (score 1):

`RenderTransform` isn't supposed to effect layout, which it would do if it changed `ActualSize`.  If you use `LayoutTransform` it should change these values, but it is a relatively simple calculation to find the new size from the old size and the scale factors.

Comment: I see. But in windows phone 8 there's no LayoutTransform is there?

Comment: @PutraKg Ahh sorry, I saw LayoutTransform and ActualSize and assumed WPF.  I don't know anything about WP8, but the information about RenderTransform will still be correct.